# Excel 2007 VBA error 1004 in web query "address of this site is not valid"

Tags: vba, excel-2007, excel-web-query

I am using the following code to get data from an html page that is stored from the web in a folder on my pc. 
I have used basically the same code in another module where it work perfectly, so I don't get why it does not work in this separate routine. The reason why I need the separate routine is because the original code is embedded in a quite complex large routine which I cannot run just to check the data of a specific file, which BTW has been analyzed without any problem with the code in the more complex set of routines. (The original piece of code follows below for comparison).

```
Dim Act As Worksheet, ActSt As Worksheet

On Error GoTo errorhandler

    Set Actbl = Workbooks("table.xlsm")
    Set ActSt = Actbl.Worksheets("act.st.")                 'query will be stored here
'some code to define path &filename
............
' Create URL
URL = path & filename

' Create Web Query & refresh it

If Len(Dir(URL)) > 0 Then               'found the file
    ActSt.Activate
    ActSt.Cells.Clear                   'clear sheet "act.st."

        'set up a table import (the URL; tells Excel that this query comes from an html file)
        Set qt = ActSt.QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:="URL;" & filename, Destination:=ActSt.Range("A4"))     'save data in "act.st."
    With qt
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh                                    'get the data
    End With
    ActSt.QueryTables.Item(1).Delete                'delete the created query, otherwise they accumulate
Else
    MsgBox "File not found"
    Exit Sub
End If
errorhandler:
    answer = MsgBox("Error " & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & ". Exit?", vbYesNo)
    If answer = vbYes Then Exit Sub
    Resume
```

Although the line "If Len(Dir(URL)) > 0 Then" makes sure that the file exists, I get an error when the code arrives at the "refresh". The message is:

> Error 1004: The address of this site is not valid. Check the address and try again. Exit?

(The text may be slightly different with an english language OS because in reality it is in spanish and this is just my translation)

I don't understand how the address can be "not valid" when the file exists obviously and is detected with "Dir(URL)" and how this problem can be resolved.

A second question, connected to this one, concerns another error 1004 that I got before when I tested this code. I had the file open in a browser while I ran the code and I got a 1004 error saying something like "error defined by application".
I imagine that this meant something like "file in use by another user" or so. Is there a way to distinguish this kind of 1004 error so the error message could be more specific? Something like an "error sub-number"? 1004 is enormously generic.

Thank you everybody who can help me find the solution, especially for the first question.

This is the original piece of code which I copied and adapted slightly for the shorter routine:

```
If Len(Dir(filename)) > 0 Then      'found the file
    GetFile = True
    ws1.Cells.Clear                 'clear sheet "act.st."

        'set up a table import (the URL; tells Excel that this query comes from an html file)
        Set qt = ws1.QueryTables.Add( _
            Connection:="URL;" & filename, Destination:=ws1.Range("A4"))     'save data in "act.st."
    With qt
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = False
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
        .Refresh                                'get the data
    End With
    ws1.QueryTables.Item(1).Delete              'delete the created query, otherwise they accumulate
Else
    GetFile = False
End If
```

Comment: Have you checked that the server returns a 200 OK HTTP response code when you request the file?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. The problem is resolved (see below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have not set the values of two variables i.e. path and filename which are building up the URL resulting in null value for URL. Please double check the path and filename variables and if they are set correctly. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed the error was there, although slightly different. Both path and filename were defined and then combined to the variable URL. This is what I checked with the Dir function and got ok, but then in the query I used only filename instead of URL. Your hint helped me find the error. Kudos.